# iOS : How to calculate total number of week in selected year

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

How can we calculate total number fo week in selected year?

suppose i select year 2000 then it should be calculate total number of year in 2000 year.

thanks in advance.

Comment: @NDoc: link you provide is not userfull for me.

Comment: @NDoc here is my code:- (NSInteger) getNumberOfWeeks : (NSDate *) fromDate {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:fromDate];
    return [components weekOfYear];
}                       NSDateFormatter *dateformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformater setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateformater dateFromString:@"2015-01-01"];
    
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[self getNumberOfWeeks:date]);

Comment: @NDoc: it return 1 actully i need week of 2000 year

Answer (score 0):

Get the weeks of a given year -

```
var dateformater = NSDateFormatter()
dateformater.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd"
var dateString:String = "2015-01-1"
let date:NSDate = dateformater.dateFromString(dateString)!
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfYear, inUnit: .Year, forDate: date)
print("weekOfYear = \( Int (components.length))")
```

Comment: range of unit return NSRange or BOOL value

Comment: rangeOfUnit  returns NSRange